# How could we calculate traveled distance, with big numbers‽

Tags: java, math, int, double, calculus

I am currently solving this kata: ["How far I will go?"](https://www.codewars.com/kata/how-far-will-i-go/train/java)!

The description says:

> You have recently discovered that horses travel in a unique pattern -
> they're either running (at top speed) or resting (standing still).
>
> Here's an example of how one particular horse might travel:
>
> The horse Blaze can run at 14 metres/second for 60 seconds, but must
> then rest for 45 seconds.
>
> After 500 seconds Blaze will have traveled 4200 metres.
>
> Your job is to write a function that returns how long a horse will
> have traveled after a given time.

Input:

```
totalTime - How long the horse will be traveling (in seconds)

runTime - How long the horse can run for before having to rest (in seconds)

restTime - How long the horse have to rest for after running (in seconds)

speed - The max speed of the horse (in metres/second)
```

I have already done the calculus by hand:

Given: speed = 14, runTime = 60, restTime = 45, totalTime = 500

-> To calculate how much time does the horse run we calculate the following:

totalTime / (runTime + restTime) = 500 / (60 + 45) = 500 / 105 = 4.76...
roundUp(totalTime) = 5

totalRunTime = 5 * runTime = 5 * 60 = 300

--> To calculate how much distance has the horse traveled:

x = speed * totalRunTime = 14 * 300 = 4200

I have translated it as the following code:

```
public class Kata {

    public static int travel(int totalTime, int runTime, int restTime, int speed) {
      int totalRunTime = 0;

      if(totalTime < runTime){
        totalRunTime = totalTime;
      }else{
        totalRunTime = (int)Math.ceil( (double)totalTime/(runTime + restTime) ) * runTime;
      }

      return speed * totalRunTime;
    }
}
```

When we run the basic tests it gives the expected output:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;


public class KataTest {

    @Test
    public void exampleTests() {
        assertEquals(4200, Kata.travel(500, 60, 45, 14));
        assertEquals(1120, Kata.travel(1000, 10, 127, 14));
        assertEquals(1000, Kata.travel(100, 10, 0, 10));
        assertEquals(1000, Kata.travel(100, 10, 0, 10));
        assertEquals(450, Kata.travel(25, 50, 120, 18));
    }
}
```

However when we test it with the advanced examples, with bigger numbers, it shows unaccurate results.

For example:

Given: speed = 6, runTime = 34, restTime = 180, totalTime = 99094; the expected output is 94524, however the code I posted gives us 94656

I have written the trace by hand to understand what my code does:

-> To calculate the total time this horse runs:

totalTime / (runTime + restTime) = 99094 / (34 + 180) = 99094 / 214 = 463.05...
roundUp(totalTime) = 464

totalRunTime = 464 * runTime = 464 * 34 = 15776

--> To calculate how far has the horse traveled:

x = speed * totalRunTime = 6 * 15776 = 94656

So then the test which fails is:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;


public class KataTest {

    @Test
    public void biggerTests() {
        assertEquals(84954920, Kata.travel(35869784, 90, 100, 5));
    }
}
```

I have the intuition that the code has to be improved in the conversion from double to int or in the rounding with Math.ceil, but I don't know why or how to solve it. Here is the line I think we could improve:

```
totalRunTime = (int)Math.ceil( (double)totalTime/(runTime + restTime) ) * runTime;
```

I have also read:

- [Calculate traveled distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548685/calculate-traveled-distance)
- [AnyLogic: How to calculate pedestrian traveled distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021286/anylogic-how-to-calculate-pedestrian-traveled-distance)
- [Calculate distance traveled (not distance between)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628576/calculate-distance-traveled-not-distance-between)
- [How to calculate the total distance traveled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376156/how-to-calculate-the-total-distance-traveled)
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_ceil.htm

Comment: if calculating by hand gives `94656` but expected is `94524` then the problem is the calculation, not rounding. (in this case take `463*214` (rounded down) to get `99082` for whole *cycle*; now there are only 12 seconds left so horse will not run the full 18 seconds, as is being calculated by given algorithm)

Comment: or a trivial example, horse must rest 60 seconds after running 60 seconds, total time is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the rounding.
Let's look at the example `travel(35869784, 90, 100, 5)`.

According to your formula `35869784/(100+90) = 188788.336`, rounding up gives us 188789, multiplying by `runTime`, and by `speed` gives us 84,955,050 meters while the right answer is 84,954,920. This isn't a rounding problem. The formula is wrong.

Why? Consider the run after the last rest. The horse already ran 188,788 full iterations of 90s + 100s, during which it covered a distance of 84,954,600 meters over 35,869,720 seconds. After those "full" runs, the horse now has only 64 seconds left to run, which is less than `runTime`!

How far does the horse run in 64 seconds? 320 meters. So the total is `84,954,600 + 320 = 84,954,920` meters.